# IEF - Setting Default Value in initial SelfAssertedAttributeProvider - passing as OutputClaim to next step in the journey not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Attempting to find any way (tried endless combinations) to ***default a value*** from the initial journey step 1 SelfAssertedAttributeProvider (api.**selfasserted**) and output into claims bag for downstream usage

- [OutputClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#when-you-should-use-output-claims) as default value

  `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EnvironmentId" DefaultValue="12345" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />`

I want to use it from the claim bag in the next orchestration step's "Sign**Up**" SelfAssertedAttributeProvider (api.localaccount**signup**)

- [InputClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#input-claims)
- So that I can ultimately "output" it to the SelfAssertedAttributeProvider ValidationTechnicalProfile as a RestfulProvider as [InputClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#input-claims) to the REST API

I have tried:

- SelfAssertedAttributeProvider [ValidationTechnicalProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#validation-technical-profiles) InputClaim/OutputClaim

  `<InputClaimClaimTypeReferenceId="EnvironmentId" />`

  `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EnvironmentId" />`
- [DefaultSSOSessionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso#defaultssosessionprovider) PersistedClaim

  `<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EnvironmentId" />`

Most interesting, I have this working in a completely different policyset -notable difference is I am trying to use the new policyset that uses [DisplayClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#display-claims) and instead of calling REST api via SelfAssertedAttributeProvider ValidationProfile - I am using the input directly to rest via ClaimsExchange step in journey.

Comment: Is your claim being output by a technical profile called by the user journey directly? That is the only way to output a claim to the next orchestration step.

Comment: Thanks your comment gave me confidence i was heading in the right direction :) 
 Assuming the "Sign Up Now" functionality bypasses the initial journey step for ```SelfAssertedAttributeProvider``` as everything attempted there did not work.  Turns out i could either default the input claim into the 2nd step of the journey OR back all the way up to the ```RelyingParty TechnicalProfile``` and default there (works best for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "Sign Up Now" functionality bypasses the initial journey step for SelfAssertedAttributeProvider as everything attempted there did not work.

Instead of attempting to default an `OutputClaim`, back all the way up to the earliest step in your `RelyingParty TechnicalProfile` and default as an `InputClaim`

Example:

```xml
    ...
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EnvironmentId" DefaultValue="12345" />
      </InputClaims>
    ...
```

The claim is successfully sent in the downstream Journey TechnicalProfile as an Input Claim.

Notable Limitation: cannot default claims via claim resolvers here :(